# Getting exception "Value cannot be null" while resolving an object by Unity

Tags: c#, wpf, inversion-of-control, unity-container, prism

I've met an exception while resolving the object using **Unity** container:

> Message   "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: container" 
>         Source  "Microsoft.Practices.Unity" string

I have a **Prism** application where I have **ServiceModule**. **ServiceModule** just has interface and its implementation:

```
public interface ICommonService
{
    string SomeStorage { get; set; }        
}

public class CommonService : ICommonService
{
    string fooStorage=DateTime.Now.ToString();
    public string FooStorage
    {
        get
        {
           return fooStorage;
        }
        set
        {
            fooStorage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FooStorage");                                
        }
    }
}
```

I create a single instance of `ICommonService` in **ViewModelA** of **ModuleA**. It works okay:

```
unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
unityContainer.RegisterType<ICommonService, CommonService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
IMyService someFoo = unityContainer.Resolve<ICommonService>();
someFoo.FooStorage = "AAAOOOBBB";
```

Then I want to read this data in **viewModelB** of **ModuleB**. And this code throws an exception:

```
ICommonService someFoo = unityContainer.Resolve<ICommonService>();
string str=someFoo.FooStorage;
```

The exception says:

> Message   "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: container" 
>         Source  "Microsoft.Practices.Unity" string

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are `IMyService` and `MyService`?

Comment: Is it `ICommonyService` or `IMyService`?

Comment: In `viewModelB`, how do you get an instance of the container? is the value of `unityContainer` null? Can you debug to verify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message that you get, most probably the value of `unityContainer` is `null`. Make sure that you initialize it correctly.